# Questioning Plutus API design decision

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, plutus-pioneer-program

In Lecture 10 from the Plutus Pioneer Programm there is a replica of the Uniswap Smart Contract built on top of Plutus. It is actually part of the standard Plutus use cases [Plutus Uniswap](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-use-cases/html/Plutus-Contracts-Uniswap.html)

To have a better user experience and to get to know it better i wanted to build a GUI around it. *If you are interested you can find it [in this github repo](https://github.com/toky03/uniswap-plutus-demo)*

Now to my question.
What is the reason behind the design decision for the Status endpoint of the Plutus PAB Rest API.
In order to read the funds we have **first** to call the funds Endpoint which returns nothing and **secondly** you have to call the status endpoint.

> This is the [*Frontend* Code from Lars](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/second-iteration/code/week06/app/swap-client.hs#L55-L73) where he reads the funds

This makes it very difficult if you want to have concurrent calls one for the funds and one for the pools

Why is there not a dedicated status endpoint for funds and pools?

Comment: This got me wondering too. I posted a question but never got any answer: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4908/user-interaction-with-smart-contracts  It seems, the Plutus team is not active on this forum.

Comment: I just registered for the third cohort of the ppp. There i will ask this Question in the Q&A session. As soon as i know more i will post it here.

Comment: Great, I'm looking forward. I am not participating in the cohort, but I would have a lot of questions.

Comment: the link to frontend code is broken, can you please update?

Comment: Thank you @LexTRX it is updated now

Answer (score -2):

The only way to read a state of the smart contract is using a contract instance status endpoint (`api/contract/instance/$INSTANCE_ID/status`). Other endpoints can only trigger a change of the state but they cannot return it so it's always a two step process.

Comment: This does not really answer my question.
I do already know how to read the different states. My question was why it is designed like this.
It even contradicts completely the functional approach of Haskell Language.